# Expected number of unique selections

Tags: probability, hash-function

If I'm selecting $N$ elements uniformly at random (with replacement) from $\{1, \dots, M\}$, what is the expected number of values that are selected *exactly once*?

The basis for this question originated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47066361/149138).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expected value is linear.  What is the probability that a particular value is selected exactly once?

Comment: Is that $$\Big({M-1\over M}\Big)^{N-1} \;\;\;\;  ?$$